# How to get text for in self drawn view from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've got self drawn view with text:

```
NSString* text = @"text";

UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];

NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 0.5;

NSDictionary* attirbutes =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [UIColor grayColor],   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
 font,                  NSFontAttributeName,
 shadow,                NSShadowAttributeName, nil];

CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attirbutes];

CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(0,
                             0,
                             textSize.width, textSize.height);

textRect = CGRectIntegral(textRect);

[text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attirbutes];
```

In my ViewController I want to get it from another class and draw it in my selfDrawnView. How Can I perform it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear what exactly are you asking. If you subclassed UIView with your new view class and overridden `drawRect` method there you need to add a property to hold the text you're drawing.

Then in your view controller you just pass the text to that property and call `[myCustomView setNeedDisplay]` to force redrawing.